# Metamask Get user profile image and username

Tags: javascript, metamask

[image]

I saw this project, and as you can see they are some meta data like the user image and the username of the user. I want to get the user profile picture URL. I don't want to generate the profile picture myself, currently im removing the "0x" and get the first to 5th charecters. I'm using ethers.js to do this.

Comment: You're going to need to tell us what "this project" is and where to find it, along with the page you are referring to in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not GENERETED by metamask, you have to generate it yourself

Answer (score 0):

For the profile image, you can use this react lib https://github.com/marcusmolchany/react-jazzicon then you can use it like this:

```js
import Jazzicon, { jsNumberForAddress } from 'react-jazzicon'

export default function App () {
  const address = '0x431330f4ad94e54cDe5C3eBE7f1494931c6B370e';
  …

  return (
    <Jazzicon diameter={100} seed={jsNumberForAddress(address)} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a package that can solve your problem and is very convenient to use (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cfx-kit/wallet-avatar)

Demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cfx-kit-wallet-avatar-demo-beqzvz

```
import { generateAvatarURL } from '@cfx-kit/wallet-avatar'
export default function App() {
    // ...
    return <img src={generateAvatarURL(account)} alt='account-avatar' />
}
```